# Replace URL Path Keeping Only Last Part - DB Query

Tags: php, mysql

We have multiple URL's in the database like:

```
http://www.example.com/_73737337/dir1/dir2/image.jpg
http://www.example.com/_892/direc/picture.png
http://www.example.com/_029929292929/dir/did/dic/dif/gallery.gif
```

All different length paths, different directories etc.  What I need is to keep the file name at the end and replace everything before it with a new domain and directory.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/_73737337/dir1/dir2/image.jpg
```

Will become:

```
http://www.newexample.com/images/image.jpg
```

AND

```
http://www.example.com/_029929292929/dir/did/dic/dif/gallery.gif
```

Will become:

```
http://www.newexample.com/images/gallery.gif
```

Is there any way to do this via a query to the database?  There are around 3000 URLs to update.

These URLs sit inside content and not standalone entries in the database.  So the query has to pick them out of the content field and ignore the rest of the content.

Comment: You can do it with .htaccess , sql and php. Just replace the path and update same links

Comment: I don't know all the paths as they're embedded in post content and there are around 3000 of them.  I don't want to add line by line in the htaccess.  I am not sure how I can write a sql query which is my purpose for asking to achieve what I have asked.

Comment: If you don't know all paths and they not same I am afraid you have to go one by one. I am not sure if there is a way to do it at once with just one script, I hope there is and someone help you, but if not try to combine group by the links and see how many different there are there

Comment: The start of each path is the same.  It's the inbetween section that differs between names and amount of directories which is what is causing me the issue

Comment: Try what David gave as answer seems like its what you asked for

Comment: It would be a nightmare without `regexp_replace`. If your version doesn't support that, you should write a script in PHP and update the content in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX() with '/' as the delimiter.

**Example**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_url, '/', -1) AS filename
FROM table_name
```

Here is a link to the docs for the function:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Comment: Like the answer but unfortunately I didn't specify that these URLs are within content not in their own column in the database.  So there may be 1000 words and 3 urls within those words.  I've updated the original post.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how you would accomplish that. Probably using regular expressions like Paul Spiegel mentioned above